# Identity Server 4 Client Certificate authentication with custom SecretParser/Validator

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm attempting to get Identity Server 4 to issue tokens based on user provided client certificates using smart cards. I've created a new Client as well as `SecretParser` and `SecretValidator`. Why does Identity Server expect me to hard code secrets within my Client definition. There are no secrets that make sense to hard code there. The reason I ask is because my `SecretValidator` is never ran unless I put some fake secret in the Client. When not provided I simply get a message back saying `Invalid Client`.

What is the proper way to validate a client certificate using Identity Server 4? The documentation I found in the Mutual TLS section doesn't seem to paint the whole picture and it provides example client that hard codes secrets.

[Edit]: This question is just a failure to understand what it means to do Mutual TLS in Identity Server 4. I'll leave this here but the question is sort of pointless and just illustrates my lack of understanding about how Identity Server works.

Comment: In the example of Mutual TLS it uses harded coded Secrets, but if you did the EF/SQLite quickstart guide it uses the ClientSecrets table. You can store the secrets there, if you want a more dynamic approach you just need to make an API to manage that resource

Comment: My question is about why does the Client force you to hard code secrets. It does not work unless you hard code secrets. You will get Invalid Client if you do not hard code secrets. I am currently putting my secrets in the database so no problem with that.

Comment: If you don't want a ClientSecret you need to disable it when declaring the Client on IdentityServere, check my answer and see if it works for your case. Try to clarify your question above, to have a straight answer then

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the need for a secret, when declaring Client on IdentityServer.
Just set **RequireClientSecret** to false.

Here is an example:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "js",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequirePkce = true,
    RequireClientSecret = false, // This disables the need for a secret 

    RedirectUris =           { "https://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/index.html" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "https://localhost:5003" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    }
}
```